# How to log incoming and outgoing XML from WCF requests

Tags: wcf, logging

I have a basic WCF hosted in a console app, and a basic console WCF client. How do you look at the requests sent between the two apps (over localhost)?

Should I use something like 'Wireshark' or would it be possible to log out the incoming and outgoing response objects in visual Studio?

I'm already creating an `log.svclog` file by the system.diagnostics directive in the App.config file, but can't find the actual request and response xml:

```
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>

<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\log\log.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Which I got from Stack Overflow (I can't remember where)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure message logging, which is separate from just WCF tracing, which is what you have configured above. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx.