# IIS: How to log ws request and response with body data?

Tags: iis, logging

i have a wcf web service running on IIS 10. 
I need to log every request and response with body data. 
How to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Massimo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128210/how-to-log-incoming-and-outgoing-xml-from-wcf-requests

Comment: thanks for the link

Comment: If that link answers your question, say it clearly and people can close this one as duplicate.